# What's the simplest to implement of all decent LTL-to-Buchi translation or other LTL verification algorithms?

Tags: lo.logic, automata-theory, model-checking, program-verification, linear-temporal-logic

I'm writing a [toy modelchecker](http://github.com/jkff/minxmod), and I'm at the point where it's time to implement LTL to Buchi automata translation.

For a variety of obvious reasons, I wish the algorithm to be simple :) e.g. I want the code to remain extremely clear and concise for as long as possible.

I've looked at the "local automata + eventuality automata" approach, described in multiple tutorials, but it seems to be neither simple to implement/understand (the correctness proof is quite large), nor does it yield small automata. So I'm not implementing it until I'm sure I won't regret it :)

So, I'd be grateful for references to papers describing simple and efficient algorithms for this translation, or perhaps simple and inefficient ones - then papers on minimization of Buchi automata would be welcome too :)

...Or perhaps there are interesting alternative approaches to LTL verification?

For reference, here's a genealogy of LTL-to-Buchi translation algorithms http://spot.lip6.fr/wiki/LtlTranslationAlgorithms . Can anyone say something about these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One construction not listed on the [SPOT](http://spot.lip6.fr/wiki/LtlTranslationAlgorithms) website is given in a survey by Demri & Gastin, *[Specification and Verification using Temporal Logics](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/Publis/PAPERS/PDF/DG-iis09.pdf)*, 2009.  The construction is simple and yields reasonably small automata, so it can be carried out by hand for small formulæ, which is good for teaching (which is how I use it), but might also be helpful for debugging an implementation.  I wouldn't bet on it being more efficient than the one used by SPOT though.

About minimization, there is no canonical minimal Büchi automaton for a given $\omega$-regular language.  In order to get smaller automata, one can quotient the automaton by some simulation relation.  A classical paper on the subject is by Etessami, Wilke & Schuller, *[Fair Simulation Relations, Parity Games, and State Space Reduction for Büchi Automata](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.8014&rep=rep1&type=pdf)*, SIAM Journal on Computing 34: 1159--1175, 2005.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Though I'm not losing hope that even more answers are to come :)

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the translation that goes through an alternating automata. (See Vardi's paper "Alternating Automata and program verification"). It's a very elegant translation from LTL to alternating automata and then you can use Mihano Ayashi (which is also elegant - it's a double subset construction) to reach a non deterministic Buchi automata.